# How do I get the last value in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I retrieve the last value in a column, when the column has a variable number of rows?

I figured how to get the row number, e.g.:

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
```

How do I use that to get the value in the cell?

e.g. `if lastRow = 8794`, I want to get the value in cell `K8794`.

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Value`

Comment: Do you have any better solution in your mind except for the solutions you have already got? If not, why didn't you mark any of those as your selected answer @Ashley?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to retrieve the last value in a column, from the comment left by @ScottCraner:

> Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Value

Answer (score 3):

try

```
range("K" & lastRow).value
```

after you get a value for **lastRow**

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw another alternative out there - you can use a `Range` variable to get the cell, then from there you can easily grab the `.Row` or `.Value` (or any other `Range` property):

```
Dim lastCell as Range
Set lastCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,"K").End(xlUp)

Debug.Print "Last cell's row is: " & lastCell.Row
Debug.Print "Last cell's value is: " & lastCell.Value
Debug.Print "Last cell's address is: " & lastCell.Address
```

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways you can get the value of last cell with a value in column K...

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox Range("K" & lastRow).Value
'OR
MsgBox Cells(lastRow, "K").Value
'OR
MsgBox Cells(lastRow, 11).Value     'here 11 is the column index for column K
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Sub ok()
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print Cells(lastRow, 11).Value
End Sub
```